# Почему RequestDispatcher не меняет url в строке браузера?

Tags: java, url, servlet

Есть фильтр который передает управление определенному сервлету таки образом:

```
req.getRequestDispatcher("all_proposes").forward(req, resp);
```

Есть сервлет которой привязан к данному `url`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AllProposes</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ru.pravvich.servlet.ProposesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AllProposes</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/all_proposes</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

И возвращает `jsp` страницу таким образом:

```
public class ProposesServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/view/all_proposes.jsp")
                .forward(req, resp);
    }
}
```

Фильтр перенаправляет запросы из корня `http://localhost:8080/`, и я хотел чтобы после передачи управления, путь в браузере клиента выглядел `http://localhost:8080/all_proposes`, однако не смотря на то что страница в ответ приходит правильно, `url` на клиенте не меняется.

Можно ли как-то сделать что бы путь менялся без `resp.sendRedirect()`, так как лишних запросов тоже делать не хочется. И если это возможно то как?

Comment: Почитайте про отличия между redirect и forward в сервлетах. Forward не работает напрямую с клиентом (браузером), redirect работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Клиент в любом случае должен каким-то образом узнать о том, что сервер перенаправляет его, так, что без лишних "телодвижений" не обойтись. 
Используйте redirect.

[RequestDispatcher.forward() vs HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047122/requestdispatcher-forward-vs-httpservletresponse-sendredirect)
[Difference between JSP forward and redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068891/difference-between-jsp-forward-and-redirect)